# How to iterate string with blank?

Tags: bash, shell

I have next code:

```
line="95:p1=a b c 95:p2=d e 96:p1=a b c 96:p2=d e"

for l in $line; do
    echo $l
done
```

I got next:

```
95:p1=a
b
c
95:p2=d
e
96:p1=a
b
c
96:p2=d
e
```

But in fact `a b c` is a whole string in my business, so if possible I could get next with some ways?

```
95:p1=a b c
95:p2=d e
96:p1=a b c
96:p2=d e
```

Comment: You can use GNU `grep`: `grep -o '[0-9]*:[^=]*[^0-9]*' <<< "$line"`, but that will fail if the substrings `a b c`, `d e`, etc. contain a digit or the numbers just before the `:` contain a non-digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash

```bash
read -ra f <<<"$line"    # split the string into words
n=${#f[@]}
i=0
lines=()
while ((i < n)); do
    l=${f[i++]}
    until ((i == n)) || [[ ${f[i]} =~ ^[0-9]+: ]]; do
        l+=" ${f[i++]}"
    done
    lines+=( "$l" )
done
declare -p lines
```

outputs

```
declare -a lines=([0]="95:p1=a b c" [1]="95:p2=d e" [2]="96:p1=a b c" [3]="96:p2=d e")
```

Now you can do

```bash
for l in "${lines[@]}"; do
    do_something_with "$l"
done
```

---

Or [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), and capture the lines with bash builtin [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile)

```bash
mapfile -t lines < <(sed -E 's/ ([0-9]+:)/\n\1/g' <<< "$line")
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/tzG64M/1) for used regex.

```
echo "$line"
95:p1=a b c 95:p2=d e 96:p1=a b c 96:p2=d e

awk -v RS='[0-9]{2}:p[0-9]=[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z]( [a-zA-Z]|$)*' 'RT{print RT}' <<<"$line"
```

Output with shown samples will be as follows:

```
95:p1=a b c
95:p2=d e
96:p1=a b c
96:p2=d e
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With any POSIX `awk` please try following `awk` code:

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/[0-9]{2}:p[0-9]=[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z]( [a-zA-Z]|$)*/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' <<<"$line"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with regular parameters. If you want a collection of strings that can contain whitespace, use an array.

```
line=("95:p1=a b c" "95:p2=d e" "96:p1=a b c" "96:p2=d e")

for l in "${line[@]}"; do
    echo "$l"
done
```

Otherwise, you'll need some way of distinguishing between "literal" spaces and "delimiter" spaces. (Maybe the latter is followed by `<num>:`, but that logic is not trivial to implement using `bash` regular expressions. You would probably be better off using a more capable language instead of trying to do this in `bash`.)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> echo "${line}" | 
>
> mawk 'BEGIN { FS=RS="^$"(ORS="") } gsub(" [^ :]+:","\1&") + gsub("\1.","\n")^_'
> ```

```
95:p1=a b c
95:p2=d e
96:p1=a b c
96:p2=d e
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE) option, would you please try:

```
grep -Po "\d+:.*?(?=(?:\s*\d+:|$))" <<< "$line"
```

Output:

```
95:p1=a b c
95:p2=d e
96:p1=a b c
96:p2=d e
```

Explanation of the regex `\d+:.*?(?=(?:\s*\d+:|$))`:

- `\d+:` matches digits followed by a colon. It will match `95:` or `96:`.
- `.*?(?=pattern)` matches the shortest sequence of characters
  followd by the `pattern`. `(?=pattern)` is a lookahead assertion
  which is not included in the mathed result.
- The `pattern` above is described as `(?:\s*\d+:|$)`, an alternation of
  `digits followed by a colon` or `end of the string`. The former
  matches the starting portion of the next item. The `\s*` before
  `\d+` matches a zero or more space character(s) which trims the
  whitespace(s) from the matched result.

If you want to iterate over the divided substrings, you can say:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    echo "$i"   # or whatever you want to do with "$i"
done < <(grep -Po "\d+:.*?(?=(?:\s*\d+:|$))" <<< "$line")
```